# How to fetch logged in use details before initializing the application using JWT token from Cookies

Tags: angular, angular-guards

I have an angular application where I am generating JWT token using SSO login. Now, I want to fetch logged-in user details before initializing the application and store the data on run time.
I also want to use user data in Route guards to validate if the user belongs to any specific group.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) in your app.module, something along the lines of:

```
const initConfig =
    srv: UserService) =>
    () => {
        const loadConfigPromise = srv.initialize();
        loadConfigPromise.then(() => {
            ...
        });
        return loadConfigPromise;
    };

@NgModule({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                    useFactory: initConfig,
                    multi: true,
                    deps: [UserService],
                },
            ],
        imports: [
         ...
        ],
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But is it fine to get logged in user details in APP_INITIALIZER?
As APP_INITIALIZER will be executed all the time whether the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why not. When I enter gmail.com in my browser, it will use a similar process to determine that I have logged in  recently and it will just show me my Inbox, without asking me to log in again.